# Is it possible to use Jquery AJAX with PHP using MVC architecture?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

The problem is that I have recently found out about MVC, and I want to port my current project to use the MVC architecture. My current project uses Jquery `AJAX` to handle most of the calls and I dont want to just scrap my js code. I'm pretty much a beginner so I was wondering if there was anyway to use Jquery `AJAX` with PHP if I'm following the MVC architecture. If there is how would I go about handling it. Also I am aware of prewritten frameworks, but I find the concepts easier to understand if I write my own code for the 1st project.

Comment: Lol! MVC would not exists if nobody could not use Javascript or Jquery in MVC Architecture ! :p

Comment: Ah I figured. How would I go about implementing it? Would the AJAX make calls to the controller or a separate php file?

Comment: yeah , you can processes ajax request from a controller

Comment: you should make ajax to controller make output there or if there html needed use also controllers+view combination to output html snippets

Comment: Sweet that really clears things up thank guys! Now I just have to figure out how to implement it :P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course that's possible.
I usually create folders in my project such as: Model, View, Static and two PHP files index.php and Controller.php. Also I found out recently that it's better to create one controller for each class but I think that for small learning projects one controller is enough and even for bigger projects it doesn't go against MVC philosophy. 
So imagine you have html form, from where you want to register new Note.

**notes.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="Controller.php">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description"/>
    <input type="Button" value="Add" onclick="addNote();"/>
</form>
```

**ajax.js**

```
function addNote()
{     
    var formElements = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
    var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("Code", "1");
        formData.append("Sequence", "1");
    for(var i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++)
        formData.append(formElements[i].name, formElements[i].value);
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            {
                //doSomething
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("POST", "Controller.php");
        xmlHttp.send(formData);
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST["Code"] && !empty($_POST["Sequence"]))
    {
        if($_POST["Code"] == "1")
        {
            switch($_POST["Sequence"])
            {
                case 1:
                    $noteObj = new Note();
                        $noteObj->create($_POST);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Then you will create Note class, with private fields, accessors and so on. Main idea is to divide your code and make it manageable which means that you can change User-Interface without changing back-end side as you have controller and classes which will return result to all requests, even if you send requests from command line tools such as curl. 
MVC is as simple as it's main goal and idea. It improves code re-usability and also flexibility in terms of helping you better monitor and upgrade it sequentially.

Comment: If you will have any questions you can check one of my projects here: https://github.com/DavidDeme/NBGRSS

Comment: I don't think the guy who asked the question asked for any kind of source code ...

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the time you took. I finally figured it out hahaha.

Comment: @PavDis If my post helped you to solve problem, than you should mark my post :)))